I am having issues to get the piece of code in my snippet whith the html labels
This is my snippet and what I hope to get when I write "html-em" in my html file:
{
"HTML EM template": {
    "prefix": "html-em",
    "body": [
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>My Website</title>
            
        </head>
        <body>
            <main>
                <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>  
            </main>

        </body>
        </html> 

    ]

    "description": "HTML Template Base for English Menu"
    }
}

This is what I am getting:
en
UTF-8
viewport
width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0
X-UA-Compatible
ie=edge

No idea what is happening but I am not getting the expected piece of code

Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the language/framework you're using

How is that JSON template interpreted?

I wrote my snippet in html.json

And I am working in VScode

@irisk120 Why are you putting HTML in a JSON file? What happens to the .json file after that?
